# Want create function using multithread Powershell with dynamical variables

Tags: multithreading, powershell, runspace

I try to do a function using multithread (inside a Runspace) with message inside a variable but when i run the script, my value inside my variable is not show on screen result but when i add static message, it works perfectly, there is my code :

```
function Multithread_func {
   param (
$NewMultiThreadContent
    )
    $Global:NewMultiThreadContentAddScript = $NewMultiThreadContent
    "$Global:NewMultiThreadContentAddScript"

$syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$newRunspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$newRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"         
$newRunspace.Open()
$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHash",$syncHash)          
$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$Global:NewMultiThreadContentAddScript","toto",'OK','information')
})

$psCmd.Runspace = $newRunspace
$data = $psCmd.BeginInvoke()
#[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$Global:NewMultiThreadContentAddScript","toto",'OK','information')

}


Multithread_func -NewMultiThreadContent "ceci est une fenêtre test"
```

I think i located the problem with .AddScript({}) and the "{}" should be the problem because $Global:NewMultiThreadContentAddScript seems to disappear inside AddScript,

i also tried without "{}" but there no multithread and it's not what i want...

Is anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Use the `$syncHash` to pass your content into the created powershell session.  `$syncHash.Add("Content", $NewMultiThreadContent)`.  Then inside the AddScript scriptblock consume it `[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($syncHash.Content,"toto",'OK','information')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to pass data to a new powershell session

The first, already alluded to in comments, is to use `$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable()`.

```
$syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$syncHash.Add('myContent', $NewMultiThreadContent)
$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('syncHash', $syncHash)          
$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript( {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($syncHash.myContent, 'toto', 'OK', 'information') 
    })
```

It is not necessary to use a syncronized hashtable if we only need to pass in variables.  We can use `SetVariable()` to pass pretty much anything.

```
$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('newVariableName', $NewMultiThreadContent)          
$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('someOtherNewVariable', @('value1', 'value2'))          
$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript( {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(($someOtherNewVariable[0] + ': ' + $newVariableName), 'toto', 'OK', 'information') 
    })
```

Sychronized hashtables are useful for sharing data between multiple threads in a thread-safe manner, for instance accessing results of long-running scripts from the console thread, or collecting data from multiple runspaces into one collection

---

The second way to pass your variable into the script block is to add a `param()`block to your script and use the `AddArgument()`method on the PowerShell object.

```
$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript( {
        param($MyContent) 
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($MyContent, 'toto', 'OK', 'information')
    
    }).AddArgument($NewMultiThreadContent)
```

`$NewMultiThreadContent` will be passed to your scriptblock as an argument which will be placed in the first position: `$MyContent`.

Comment: Thanks, i take note from your answer !